# Is it possible to display a form by passing a filter to a field in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

**I wish I could instantiate the fields question in my class Reply when I call my form in my template**

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

Is it possible to filter fields my questions based on the page where I am. That is, if my page that I call one visit I have 2 questions that does not give me the choice between the two questions if I am in the page that is called Visit 2 and that in this visit there 3 questions it gives me the choice between his 3 questions ...

I would like to be able to filter the choices of questions when I call my ReplyForm form

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        exclude = ('user','creationDate')
```

**It is necessary that I add something in my models, my views?**

```
def access(request, instance):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    length_questions = len(questions)
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions, can_delete=True)
    formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            new_instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for new_instance in new_instances:
                new_instance.user = logged_user
                new_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/baseVisite/')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Le formulaire est incorrecte !')
            return render_to_response('polls/error.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
     'formset': formset,
     'questions':questions,
     'logged_user':logged_user,
     'numPages' : numPages
     })
```

> Edit :

I tried to define the **init** method in my forms but I can not seem to make my filter to display the questions according to the page

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        exclude = ('user','creationDate')
    def __init__(self, instance, *args,**kwargs):
        super (ReplyForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        self.fields['question'].queryset = Question.objects.filter(page = instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

When your instantiate the formset for the get request:
    `formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.none())`
You should instead pass it the questions you want to display as a queryset. You can pass any queryset so something like
 `formset = ReplyFormSet(instance=Reply.objects.filter(question='foo'))` or 
`formset = ReplyFormSet(instance=Reply.objects.exclude(question='bar'))` 
Should do what you like.

Comment: I found what I needed to change but I do not know how to make this work, it is this line : `self.fields['question'].queryset = Question.objects.filter(page = instance)`

Comment: It will have to filter by displaying the page issues or it is